# Make draw call in openGL that ONLY touches the depth buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I'm not looking to render the depth buffer to a texture, or query it for shadows or anything like that- I'm looking to essentially make a render pass that just pre-populates the depth buffer with some data before my other draw calls that will utilize its contents. However, I do NOT want this "fill the depth buffer" pass to write to the color buffer.

I'm using OpenGL 2.1 (or OpenGL ES 2), with non-fixed pipeline stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depth-only render passes are not uncommon in certain scenarios.

You can achieve that in the GL by masking all writes to the color buffer: `glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE)`. (If you use other buffers like stencil, there are separate masks for them, too.)

Another option would be to just set `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)`, however, that is not available in GLES 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can render to the depthbuffer only with the colormask set to all false.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glColorMask.xml